# CoAP blockwise transfer on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, coap

How to create a CoAP block-wise transfer on NodeJS? I use node-coap module. 
I send a request to:

```
var options = {
      host: 'coap.me',
      port: 5683,
      pathname: '/test',
      method: 'PUT',
    };
```

I also do this: `req.setOption('Block2', new Buffer([1]));` This method should create a CoAP option and mean that size of payload is 32 bytes. After that I don't know what to do. I try `for` cycle (`body` = 32 bytes):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if(i === 99){
            req.end(body);
        } else {
            req.write(body);
        }
    }
```

Everything I have is an error: `Max packet size is 1280: current is 265951`

Or if I should use different requests, how to map one after another? Because every request produce a response and my program ends after first request.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to send a big payload from client to server?
This is **Block1** not **Block2**.

[RFC7959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7959#page-7):

> Both Block1 and Block2 Options can be present in both the request and
> response messages.  In either case, the Block1 Option pertains to the
> request payload, and the Block2 Option pertains to the response
> payload.

Unfortunately, looks like there is no such out-of-box feature in node-coap.

https://github.com/mcollina/node-coap/issues/42

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah, I noticed lack of this feature and wrote function for implementing Block1